# regular expression about numbers

Tags: regex

is this regular expression valid in case I want to include numbers only up to 31 ?

'[^0-9>31]+ or it will also return alphabetic characters and I must somehow exclude them too ?

Comment: Why use regex? That's not the right tool.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: To be fair, if regex's worked the way the author hoped, they would be the right tool...

Comment: Also, to provide a sensible alternative to a regex, you'll need to tell us what language or tool you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex accepts one or more characters, each of which is not one of the following

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 >
```

What you want is:

```
/^(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/
```

Comment: You can combine this `[0-9]|[12][0-9]` to this: `[12]?[0-9]`.

Comment: Very nice.  And it doesn't backtrack.  +1

Comment: what does ?: mean? and why [01] are in square brackets ?

Comment: Placing `?:` at the beginning of a parenthesized regex component makes it "non-capturing" -- it is an optimization but does not change the meaning of the regex at all.  The expression `[01]` is a character class; it means `0` or `1`.  You could also write it as `(0|1)`.  So when I wrote `3[01]` I was saying "either 30 or 31".

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not the sonic screwdriver of text, able to magically do everything you could possibly want.  There is nothing in regular expressions that will check the value of a number.

What you need to do is two steps, written here in Perl.

```
$ok = ($s =~ /^\d{1,2}$/) && ($s < 31);
```

That checks the value of `$s` for start of the string (`^`), one or two digits (`\d{1,2}`) and then the end of the string (`$`).  If that is true, then it also checks to see that the numeric value of `$s` is less than 31.

Yes, you can use a complex regex like this from Ray Toal's answer:

```
/^(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/
```

but that is far less readable.